# Working with maximum values in SAS

Tags: count, sas, max

Hopefully a straight forward answer, but how can I determine if a variable has more then one observation that equals the maximum? For example, if the following is my data:

```
ID      Doctor  COUNT   
576434  Tim     1   
576434  Lynn    1   
576434  Moran   1   
576434  Wade    2   
576434  Ashwin  2
```

Looking at the variable "COUNT", we can see that two observations equal the maximum value 2. I would then want to flag this "ID" as having a tie. The data is already in order by ID then COUNT, so my thought was maybe to just see if the values in the last two rows equal, but hoping for a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, take a look at this strange solution...

First, your data (with a few more lines to test it out)

```
data have;
format 
    ID 8.
    Doctor  $10. 
    COUNT 8.;
input 
    @1 ID 8.
    @8 Doctor $7.
    @16 COUNT 8.;
DATALINES;
576434  Tim     1   
576434  Lynn    1   
576434  Moran   1   
576434  Wade    2   
576434  Ashwin  2   
111111  AAAAAA  1   
111111  BBBBBB  2   
111111  CCCCCC  3   
111111  DDDDDD  3   
111111  EEEEEE  3   
222222  ZZZZZZ  1   
222222  WWWWWW  2   
;
RUN;

proc sort data=have;
by ID;
run;
```

Create a dataset to help us, selecting only those max values which count > 1 by ID

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE AUX AS
SELECT 
    ID
    ,MAX(COUNT) AS AUXCOUNT
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID
        ,COUNT
        ,COUNT(*) AS COUNTOBS
    FROM HAVE
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING CALCULATED COUNTOBS > 1
    )
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
quit;
```

Merge with the first data set to flag the data when there's a tie:

```
data want;
merge
    have (in=a)
    aux (in=b);
by ID;
if count = auxcount then TIEFLAG = "TIE";
else TIEFLAG = "";
drop auxcount;
run;
```

RESULT

```
ID      DOCTOR  COUNT  FLAG
111111  AAAAAA  1   
111111  BBBBBB  2   
111111  CCCCCC  3   TIE
111111  DDDDDD  3   TIE
111111  EEEEEE  3   TIE
222222  ZZZZZZ  1   
222222  WWWWWW  2   
576434  Tim 1   
576434  Lynn    1   
576434  Moran   1   
576434  Wade    2   TIE
576434  Ashwin  2   TIE
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your dataset has additional rows for example's sake:

```
data have;
  input ID Doctor$ Count;
    datalines;
576434 Tim 1
576434 Lynn 1
576434 Moran 1
576434 Wade 2
576434 Ashwin 2
576435 Barry 8
576435 Jim 10
576435 Bart 10
576391 Tom 1
576391 Bill 2
run;
```

**Step 1: Sort your dataset by ID, *descending* Count**

```
proc sort data=have;
    by ID descending count;
run;
```

We now have the original dataset put in an order that we can work with. Next, we we'll remove duplicate max entries.

**Step 2: Remove duplicates for ID *descending* Count**

```
proc sort data=have
          out=_temp_
          dupout=dupes
          nodupkey;
    by ID descending count;
run;
```

We don't care about the output dataset from `proc sort`, but we do care about the `dupout` dataset.

```
      Dupes
ID      Doctor  Count
576434  Ashwin  2     <---- Duplicate max
576434  Lynn    1
576434  Moran   1
576435  Bart    10    <---- Duplicate max
```

**Step 3: Pick out the duplicates**

Notice that the start of each `ID` group is the max duplicate value. Since it's sorted by ID, then count in descending order, the very first entry of each `ID` group in the `dupout` dataset will get us every instance of a duplicate max. Because everything is sorted thanks to `proc sort`, this trick will work without errors.

```
data dupe_max;
    set dupes;
    by ID descending count;
    if(first.ID);

    keep ID;
run;
```

**Step 4: Merge these IDs back with the original sorted dataset**

```
data want;
    merge dupes(in=dupmax)
          have(in=all);
    by ID;

    Duplicate_Max = (have=dupes);
run;
```

Two things are going on here:

1. The `in=` option allows us to create a Boolean variable that tells us which dataset the observation is coming from. In other words, if the ID exists in `dupes`, the variable `dupmax` = 1. If the ID exists in `have`, the variable `all` = 1.
2. `variable = (logic here)` is a shorthand way of creating Boolean `1/0` variables. You can get the same result by doing:

   ```
   if(have=dupes) then Duplicate_Max = 1; else Duplicate_Max = 0;
   ```

Behind the scenes, this is what's happening:

```
                            ID from have    ID from dupes
                                     vvv    vvvvvv
ID      Doctor  Count Duplicate_Max  all    dupmax Match?
576391  Bill    2     0              1      0      No
576391  Tom     1     0              1      0      No
576434  Wade    2     1              1      1      Yes
576434  Ashwin  2     1              1      1      Yes
576434  Tim     1     1              1      1      Yes
576434  Lynn    1     1              1      1      Yes
576434  Moran   1     1              1      1      Yes
576435  Jim     10    1              1      1      Yes
576435  Bart    10    1              1      1      Yes
576435  Barry   8     1              1      1      Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to do it in SQL.  You don't even need to sort.  Assuming your source data set is "have" as either of the two other posters provided:

```
PROC SQL ;

  CREATE TABLE dupemax AS
  SELECT a.id, a.count, a.numobs
    FROM (SELECT id, count, COUNT(*) AS numobs
            FROM have
            GROUP BY id, count
         ) a     
         %* gives the number of rows with each id/count combination ;
         INNER JOIN
         (SELECT id, MAX(count) AS count
            FROM have
            GROUP BY id
         ) b     
         %* finds the id/MAX(count) value ;
         ON a.id EQ b.id AND a.count EQ b.count     
         %* so only getting the id and the MAX(count), not all "count" values ;
    WHERE a.numobs GE 2      
    %* and of the id/MAX(count), only where there were multiple rows of the MAX(count) ;
  ;

QUIT ;
```